# How do I create a new mail profile if my 'mail' applet in control panel is non responsive?

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, user-profiles, applet

I cannot get into the mail applet under Control Panel. When I click on the mail applet, I see the loading circle for a few seconds and then it disappears and nothing happens.

Environment: Windows 7 Professional box 64-bit. Office 2013. My office 2013 applications are working just fine.

Things tried:

I tried a full online repair on the Office in add\remove programs and then rebooted but experienced the same result (failure).

I uninstalled the Office 2013 suite, reinstalled it and rebooted but experienced the same result. 
I deleted the Outlook profile in the registry (after first creating a backup) but I was unable to log back into my Outlook after deleting the profile. I restored the registry entry and I logged back into my Outlook.

I cannot find any semblance of the file mlcfg.cpl to modify or add to control panel. I still can't get into the mail applet in the control panel.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: It could be an issue with your profile. You could try logging into a different user (create one if necessary, delete after testing) and see if it works there.

Comment: all my users with Microsoft Outlook 2013 experience this inability to open up the mail applet. I have tested over 5 of them now. I don't think they can all have the same issue with their profile all at once.

Comment: Agreed, but your post did not mention that you tried it, so I had to rule it out.